# Making a database of searchable profiles using forms

Tags: database, forms, survey

This is more a general topic on implementation. Basically what I want to do is allow one group of users to create a survey from a html form and allow them to post this for a second group of users to see.

I would like the second group of users to be able to fill out the forms and submit them to whoever posted the survey. I would like whoever posted the survey to be able to filter the results (by say age, sex, or other variable in the form) and I would like the first group to be able to use their form in subsequent surveys without having to re-enter data?

I have basic knowledge of HTML and CSS so my question would be how is the best way to implement this? Is it even with forms? What languages would I need to learn?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I quite get the hang of what you're trying to do but for starters there's plenty of free survey creation tools out there such as http://www.surveymonkey.com/ that might do some/what you need.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=87809) should allow you to input the survey data into a spreadsheet.